# Draw a line with Edge collider 2D using LineRenderer programmatically, but the collider is in wrong place in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the player to draw a line through the mouse, and this line has a collider, but this collider appears in the wrong place.

I have tried these methods with ScreenToWorldPoint, ScreenToViewportPoint and ScreenPointToRay, but these results are not what I want.

```
public class DrawLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject linePrefab;
    public GameObject currentLine;

    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;
    public List<Vector2> fingerPositions;
    public List<Vector2> fingerWorldPositions;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            CreateLine();
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector2 tempFingerPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Vector2.Distance(tempFingerPos, fingerPositions[fingerPositions.Count - 1]) > .1f)
            {
                UpdateLine(tempFingerPos);
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateLine()
    {
        currentLine = Instantiate(linePrefab, Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        lineRenderer = currentLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        edgeCollider = currentLine.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        fingerPositions.Clear();
        Vector3 tempMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        fingerPositions.Add(tempMousePosition);
        fingerPositions.Add(tempMousePosition);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, fingerPositions[0]);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, fingerPositions[1]);
        edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();
    }

    void UpdateLine(Vector2 newFingerPos)
    {
        fingerPositions.Add(newFingerPos);
        lineRenderer.positionCount++;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, newFingerPos);
        edgeCollider.points = fingerPositions.ToArray();
     }
}
```

The black line is drawn with a mouse and the green line is Edge collider 2D.
[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had your exact same problem some time ago in a project of mine. I fixed it by adjusting the transform.position of the linerenderer object to the location of the next point. And after setting the points, i would reset the position of the gameobject to zero (last line of code). This worked for me, because my gameobject should always be at absolute zero. But if yours doesn't, then just change it to use relative position and child it to an gameobject if it isnt already.

Here is my code, I hope it helps you.

```
public GameObject LineDrawPrefab;

private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private EdgeCollider2D edgeCollider;
private List<Vector2> edgePoints;
private GameObject activeLineGameObject;
private List<GameObject> lineGameObjects;

    private void StartLine(Vector3 start, Color color)
    {
        var targetPos = new Vector3 { x = start.x, y = start.y, z = 0.1f };

        drawing = true;
        activeLineGameObject = Instantiate(LineDrawPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        lineGameObjects.Add(activeLineGameObject);

        lineRenderer = activeLineGameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        edgeCollider = activeLineGameObject.GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        lineRenderer.sortingOrder = 1;
        lineRenderer.material = LineRendererMaterial;
        lineRenderer.startColor = color;
        lineRenderer.endColor = color;
        lineRenderer.startWidth = 0.3f;
        lineRenderer.endWidth = 0.3f;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, targetPos);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, targetPos);

        edgePoints.Clear();
        edgePoints.Add(targetPos);
        edgeCollider.points = edgePoints.ToArray();
    }

    private void ExtendLine(Vector3 nextpoint)
    {
        if (lineRenderer == null))
        {
            StartLine(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), color);
            return;
        }
        var targetPos = new Vector3 { x = nextpoint.x, y = nextpoint.y, z = 0.1f };

        lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, lineRenderer.transform.position = targetPos); // manipulate position to avoid the collider from spawning out of the object.

        edgePoints.Add(nextpoint);
        edgeCollider.points = edgePoints.ToArray();
        activeLineGameObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero; // reset position
    }
```

Edit: An additional tip. I (and you) used `Camera.main` here. This is not performant because it does an expensive lookup every time it is called. 
(`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>()`)

I suggest to cache it in start or awake and then reuse that variable. This can potentially be a huge performance gain.

```
private Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Through your answer, I finally found out that it is a problem with Transform scale.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help